# Where did Ultron come from in the 2012 Avengers Assemble cartoon?

Tags: marvel, avengers, cartoon, avengers-assemble-tv

In the 2012 Avengers Assemble cartoon TV series, where did Ultron come from?

In the episode "Thanos Triumphant" (season 2 episode 13) Ultron suddenly 'appeared' in Arsenal's body.

As far as I am aware Ultron was never so much as mentioned at any point earlier in the series. However, the Avengers seem to *know* Ultron somehow.

> Falcon: "Whoa, that's Ultron? He's even scarier than I expected!"

So **my question is, where did Ultron come from and why do the Avengers appear to know (something) about him?**

I am looking for either a canon/in-universe explanation or a "meta" explanation like something said in an interview by a producer/writer.

Answer (score 3):

This question needs some looking around. I'm just putting out my theory and this is what I think.

The two series **Avengers Assemble (AA)** and the older one **Avengers:Earth's Mightiest Heroes (AEMH)** might as well be linked. Although it is not shown in the latter, but in ***Avengers assemble S01 E08: Molecule Kid***, when Hawkeye recollects their fight with Molecule man, the flashback shows everyone in the original costumes (*which were used by the avengers in the **AEMH** series*).

So, if we assume that the two series are linked, when Ultron is destroyed by Thor in ***S02 E21: Ultron Imperative*** of the AEMH, there could have been a chance that a small part of him was stored somewhere else. Later when Ultron found a backdoor in Arsenal (in AA S02 E13: Thanos triumphant), he got into it.

Some other links between **AA** and **AEMH** could be that in the **AEMH** series, Pym quits being Ant-man and passes the mantle to Lang. The **AA** directly introduces Scott Lang as their Ant-man.

And also, Black Panther, Captain Marvel, Vision each of these characters when appeared in the AA series, it's shown as if the original Avengers (Stark, Cap etc.) already knew them.

However, there are other contradictions that do not support this theory too. Like Falcon's, Jane Foster's role differed quite a lot in the two series.

I'd like to believe that these two series are related. Nevertheless, it might also be that Marvel is tinkering a lot so they may have missed some details.

Comment: if the series are linked, then this answer doesn't actually answer the question as it doesn't explain Ultron's actual origins ;)

Comment: @NKCampbell yes. because it's answered in the Avengers:Earth's Mightiest heroes. I don't wanna spoil the fun of watching it because its damn awesome. I could still provide the origins if needed :P

Comment: Hm, this explains a lot. I haven't seen any EMH episodes, but this seems like a good enough theory as to Ultron's origins in AA.